# mongodb update is throwing a critical error

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

When I try to update a user using a web form, it runs a app.post on express. The object user is correct, but sometimes it throws a error in node console

```
app.post('/register/update', jsonParser, (request, response) => {
  let user = request.body.user;
  let users = mongoUtil.users();

  console.log(user);

  users.update({email: user.email}, user, (err, res) => {
    if(err) {
      response.sendStatus(400);
    }
    response.sendStatus(201);
  });
});
```

In node console:

```
{ _id: '578246ec9eb0587a5d67b8c9',
  email: 'test@test.com',
  zipcode: '1231-123',
  companyName: 'test',
  tradeName: 'test',
  contactName: 'Test',
  tel: '(14) 1232-1231',
  password: 'test',
  passwordConfirm: 'test',
  adress: 'test',
  adressComplement: 'test',
  adressNumber: '123' }
/home/ec2-user/ ... /mongodb/lib/utils.js:98
    process.nextTick(function() { throw err; });
                                  ^

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:346:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/home/ec2-user/ ... /node_modules/express/lib/response.js:719:10)
    at ServerResponse.contentType (/home/ec2-user/ ... /node_modules/express/lib/response.js:552:15)
    at ServerResponse.sendStatus (/home/ec2-user/ .. /node_modules/express/lib/response.js:340:8)
    at users.update (/home/ec2-user/menuWebApp/server/app.js:94:14)
    at handleCallback (/home/ec2-user/ ... /node_modules/mongodb/lib/utils.js:96:12)
    at /home/ec2-user/ ... /node_modules/mongodb/lib/collection.js:1008:42
    at commandCallback (/home/ec2-user/ ... /node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:1194:9)
    at Callbacks.emit (/home/ec2-user/ ... /node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:119:3)
    at Connection.messageHandler (/home/ec2-user/ ... /node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:358:23)
```

I'm probably dealing with a callback problem, but I don't have idea how to solve it D:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is not coming from the update statement itself its coming from your callback function.

Specifically these lines of code.

```
if(err) {
  response.sendStatus(400);
}
response.sendStatus(201);
```

What you are doing is if there is an error send the status 400, then send the status 201. The problem is once you send a response with your headers to the requestor you can't try and set the headers again.

So your code should change to:

```
if(err) {
   response.sendStatus(400);
}else{
   response.sendStatus(201);
}
```

So if an error is generated you will send a 400 response otherwise you will send a 201 response instead of trying to send a 400 response and then a 201 response immediately after.